# Quartz Java Run Jobs in Multiple Machines

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler, quartz

I have many jobs with Quartz Schedule and I execute in my java app.
 (one event on my webapp active a job to run)

My webapp runs in 4 machines with two instances each, so:

how can i make sure that the same job does not run 2 times on 2 different machines?

and how i make sure tha there are no problems with persistence in the database?

Comment: You can annotate your job with **DisallowConcurrentExecution** which will make sure multiple instances are not executed concurrently http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/api/2.2.1/org/quartz/DisallowConcurrentExecution.html

Answer (score 2):

You can configure Quartz clustering with JDBC-JobStore. Basically all your instances should share the same database, and Quartz will ensure that only one instance will run a specific job. More info can be found [here](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.1.x/configuration/ConfigJDBCJobStoreClustering.html)